# I keep getting the message loadParameters.exe has triggered a breakpoint?

Tags: c

This is my assignment I am supposed to do however whenever I run my code I get the error stated in my question.

Create a function,
return type: char
parameters: int *, int *

Inside the function, ask for two integers. Set the user responses to the int * parameters.

Prompt the user for a character.
Get their response as a single character and return that from the function.

In main:
Define two variables and call your function.
Print the result of your function and the values of your variables.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


char load(int *x, int *y);

void main()
{
    int integer1 = 0;
    int integer2 = 0;

    int *pointer1;
    int *pointer2;

    pointer1 = &integer1;
    pointer2 = &integer2;

    char returnValue;


    returnValue = load(*pointer1, *pointer2);

    printf("%c", returnValue);

    system("pause");

}

char load(int *x, int *y)
{
    char input;
    printf("Please enter two integers: ");
    scanf_s("%d %d", x, y);

    printf("Please enter a character:");
    scanf_s(" %c", &input);

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're using an IDE and you have accidentally set a breakpoint for debugging. Alternatively, consider whether removing the `system("pause");` call changes things.

Comment: Note that you should return a int from main, probably the EXIT_SUCCESS constant, and not pause your program there, certainly not in this way. There should be another way to inspect your output after the program has finished. You may want to search around for "inspecting output in <IDE>", for whatever IDE you use.

Comment: Change `returnValue = load(*pointer1, *pointer2);` to `returnValue = load(pointer1, pointer2);`.

Comment: Note that `scanf_s(" %c", &input);` expects both a space *and* a character. Considering removing the first space in the string. Ditto for "%d %d" in the other `scanf_s` call, which expects an integer, *then* a space, *then* another integer.

Comment: "... and the values of your variables.": you've forgotten this part.

Comment: You are passing 0 to load function. scanf_s is performing a NULL pointer dereference and hence its triggering a break point inside the library.

Comment: Turn on ALL your compiler warnings and you should be fine.